# Update multiple colums only if another row has certain value

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I'm trying to clean some fields of one of my tables(`profiles`), some columns has a phone number as value.

```
+--------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
| id     |     phone    |    address    |  zip_code    |
+--------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
|      1 |  1234567890  |   1234567890  |     45455    |
|      2 |  7777888800  |   56 st.      |  7777888800  |
+--------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
```

How I can update all the fields where the value is equal to the phone field, and clean up them as follows?

```
+--------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
| id     |     phone    |    address    |  zip_code    |
+--------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
|      1 |  1234567890  |               |     45455    |
|      2 |  7777888800  |   56 st.      |              |
+--------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
```

Comment: If this is a one-off exercise with such limited number of fields, I would write separate queries for each of the fields to be cleansed.

Answer (score 0):

If it only those two fields, you can do this with 2 simple queries that validate each field:

```
UPDATE profiles
SET address = NULL
WHERE address = phone

UPDATE profiles
SET zip_code = NULL
WHERE zip_code = phone
```

Comment: What if I have more fields, like 8 or so, also I have a lot of profiles, any idea?

Comment: Don't have much experience with mysql, but there is probably something similar. In Oracle, I would go for a [PL/SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL) , playing with table's metadata, you could iterate through all columns and compare them with phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply update all the columns using `case` statement like below

```
update profile2 p
set 
p.address = case when cast(p.phone as char(20)) = p.address then null else p.address end,
p.zipcode = case when p.phone = p.zipcode then null else p.zipcode end,
p.fax = case when p.phone = p.fax then null else p.fax end;
```

I have also include one more column `fax` for your reference.

Comment: As the PO says in previous answer's comment, he needs a solution for variable fields, and tables. This is just an abbreviation for previous answer, which by the way, is less performant.